# Read from json on live server

Tags: c#, json

I have a JSON file.

```
    public static string RepStatusJsonFile = @"Statuses.json";
```

as I try to read from it using StreamReader,

```
    public static Dictionary<string, string> LoadRepStatuses()
{
    Dictionary<string, string> list = new Dictionary<string, string>();

    StreamReader read = new StreamReader(RepStatusJsonFile);
    string json = read.ReadToEnd();
    DataSet ds = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<DataSet>(json);

    for (int i = 0; i < RepStatuses; i++)
    {
        list.Add(ds.Tables[0].Rows[i][0].ToString(), ds.Tables[0].Rows[i][1].ToString());
    }

    return list;
}
```

I get this error:

```
Could not find file 'C:\Windows\SysWOW64\inetsrv\statuses.json'.
```

Comment: Do you have a file by that name at that location?

Comment: Where is your json file located? Is it present at path 'C:\Windows\SysWOW64\inetsrv?

Comment: Pretty sure you want to do a `MapPath` somewhere in there...

Comment: It is currently located in the Admin folder on my server.
I'm trying to access it just as you would try to access an .aspx page

Comment: You access aspx pages from 'C:\Windows\SysWOW64\inetsrv'?

Comment: Change your code to use an absolute (bad idea) or relative (better idea) path, so that the code that reads the file looks in the right place

Answer (score 0, accepted):

SOLVED!

Changed it to:

```
        StreamReader read = new StreamReader(System.Web.HttpContext.Current.Server.MapPath(@"Statuses.json"));
```

Thanks to Mike McCaughan.